# How to make dynamic form controls?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, dynamic

I want to make a form group with an unknown amount of form controls. (according to my data base).
I tried to do it using `FormArray`, `FormBuilder` like this:

```
criterions:Criterion[]=[];
fb:FormBuilder= new FormBuilder();
preferencesForm:FormGroup=new FormGroup({
  aliases: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.control('')
  ])
});

get aliases() {
  return this.preferencesForm.get('aliases') as FormArray;
}

  constructor( private service:flightsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getAllCriterion().subscribe(data=>{
      this.criterions=data;
      this.criterions.forEach(a=>this.aliases.push(this.fb.control('')))
    });
  }
```

and my HTML is:

```
<div [formGroup]="preferencesForm">
<div formArrayName="aliases">
    <div *ngFor="let alias of aliases.controls; let i=index">
      <label>
        {{criterions[i].criterionName}}
        <mat-radio-group formControlName="i" aria-label="Select an option">
            <mat-radio-button [value]="true"  >want</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button [value]="false" >don't want</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button [value]="" >don't care</mat-radio-button>
          </mat-radio-group>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In ts

```
constructor(
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder){
 this.createForm();
}

createForm(){
this.preferencesForm=this._formBuilder.group({
aliases: this._formBuilder.array([])
})
}


createFormArray() {
    let formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      radio: [''],


    });


    return formGroup;
  }


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getAllCriterion().subscribe(data=>{
      this.criterions=data;
      this.criterions.forEach(a=>this.aliases.push(createFormArray())
    });
```

In HTML

```
<div [formGroup]="preferencesForm">
<div formArrayName="aliases">
    <div *ngFor="let alias of aliases.controls; let i=index">
      <label>

        <mat-radio-group formControlName="radio" aria-label="Select an option">
            <mat-radio-button [value]="true"  >want</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button [value]="false" >don't want</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button [value]="" >don't care</mat-radio-button>
          </mat-radio-group>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem didn't fixed yet... it still showes the errors: **Cannot find control with path: 'aliases -> i**
 what else can I do?

Comment: At which line no you are getting error in HTML and ts